# How to upload large raster dataset to ArcGIS Online

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I have trouble adding large raster dataset to ArcGIS Online. Esri website suggests using Create Map Tile Package- tool to create layer that works in ArcGIS Online.

The problem is that I need high level of detail for this data. If I raise level of detail parameters, the file size is apparently too high and the outcome is multiple bundle files instead of one tpkx/tpk file. I can't find a way to use these bundle files in ArcGIS Online. If I select very low level of detail, I can upload tpkx file to ArcGIS Online succesfully.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: My experience with uploading a raster to AGOL is that it turns it into an image. So if your intention (which you don't specify) is a layer that you can click on and retrieve a cell value then you are barking up the wrong tree, as I was. It needs to be an [imagery layer](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-imagery-layers.htm) which of course costs...